# Conversão decimal fracionário para decimal em VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia, preciso realizar um programa que converte um decimal fracionário para binário.
Caso não tenha uma representação exata, devo informar uma quantidade de dígitos significativos. Entretanto não estou conseguindo realizar.
Meu código:

```
Sub Binario_P_Decimal2()

    Dim Numero As Single, Binario As String, fra As Single, BinarioFra As String, resto As Single
    Numero = InputBox("Informe o seu número ")
    fra = Numero - Int(Numero)
    NDS = 9
    Do While Numero > 0
        If (Numero Mod 2) = 0 Then
            Binario = Binario & "0"
        Else
            Binario = Binario & "1"
        End If
        Numero = Numero \ 2
    Loop
    Do While fra <> 0# And i < NDS
        If Int(fra) >= 1 Then
            BinarioFra = BinarioFra & "1"
        Else
            BinarioFra = BinarioFra & "0"
        End If
        fra = fra * 2 + fra
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox (" O seu número binário é " & StrReverse(Binario) & BinarioFra)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia
O Excel tem uma Worksheet.function chamada Dec2Bin. Já experimentou?

Pode também experimentar (codegrapper.com):

```
    Function DecToBin$(ByVal n&)
      Do
         DecToBin = n Mod 2 & DecToBin
         n = n \ 2
      Loop While n
    End Function
```

Exemplo: MsgBox DecToBin(9512489)    '<--resultado: 100100010010011000101001